# Associating same model object multiple times with different order/datetime

Tags: ruby, oop, ruby-on-rails-4, model

There is a Smil model, Playlist model, and Video model. A smil has many playlists, and a playlist has many videos. Once a playlists is created, I would like it to be possible to add the same playlist to the smil but with a different datetime associated with the playlist. If I add the datetime attribute to the playlist, it will make it so that each time that playlist is used, it will have that datetime. To clarify further, there is a playlist1 and playlist2. I would like the smil file to contain playlist1 @ datetime1, playlist2 @ datetime2, playlist1 @ datetime3, playlist2 @ datetime4. How should I setup/modify the Playlist model or Smil model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create another model that holds a playlist and a datetime. It delegates all calls to the underlying playlist instance except the datetime.

More generally this is known as a proxy object. It's API should match the public API of the object it's proxying (a playlist in this case) and it holds an instance of the proxied object that it defers all the method calls, that it doesn't implement itself, to.

Comment: I did as mentioned and used a PlaylistProxy model and had delegate in the model to the Playlist. Worked exactly as needed, thanks.